# Make AWS MFA required for all users policy not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've added a policy to a group to make MFA required, following the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam_mfa-selfmanage.html):

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListActions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["iam:ListUsers", "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices"],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserToCreateVirtualMFADevice",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserToManageTheirOwnMFA",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserToDeactivateTheirOwnMFAOnlyWhenUsingMFA",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["iam:DeactivateMFADevice"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "BlockMostAccessUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotAction": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListUsers",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "BoolIfExists": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, since adding this policy, users in that group are able to interact with AWS normally via the console but not using `boto3` or the CLI. Using the policy simulator also shows that any action on any service is denied because of the following section:

```json
{
  "Sid": "BlockMostAccessUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "NotAction": [
    "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
    "iam:EnableMFADevice",
    "iam:ListMFADevices",
    "iam:ListUsers",
    "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
    "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "BoolIfExists": {
      "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug but something I completely overlooked. With this policy active, calls made from the CLI also need to be MFA authenticated via a session token.

I've added the following to my `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
set_aws_credentials() {
    unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
    export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="eu-central-1"
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="CHANGE_ME"
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="CHANGE_ME"
    export AWS_MFA_DEVICE_ARN="CHANGE_ME"    
}

update_mfa_token() {
    set_aws_credentials

    TMP_CREDENTIALS=($(aws sts get-session-token --serial-number $AWS_MFA_DEVICE_ARN --token-code $1 \
      | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId, .Credentials.SecretAccessKey, .Credentials.SessionToken'))

    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${TMP_CREDENTIALS[0]}"
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${TMP_CREDENTIALS[1]}"
    export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="${TMP_CREDENTIALS[2]}"
}
```

Now in a new shell I `update_mfa_device 123456` before running CLI commands and everything works as expected. This is an example and inspired by [this](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli) thread.